# got to iMessage storyboard from main Stoyboard, iOS, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage

I am trying to connect my main app so that when I press a button it goes to the iMessage extension. I have set up the storyboard reference and selected it to the iMessage storyboard. But on runtime I get an error saying

> : error: Did not find storyboard named "MainInterface" referenced from ShowAndComments.storyboard
>   Command LinkStoryboards failed with a nonzero exit code.

[image: The Link]

Comment: so.. you want your app to redirect the user to the imessages app, right? or do you want to open a compose sheet that sends a message over imessages

Comment: I want to open a compose message sheet that will send over iMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detele that segue and on your button action instantiate programatically a MFMessageComposeViewController and present it.

> OBJ-C example

**Create your MFMessageComposeViewController**

```
NSArray *recipents = @[@"12345678", @"72345524"];
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:recipents];
[messageController setBody:message];
```

**Show it** (vc should be an instance of UIViewController or a subclass of it)

```
[vc presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for you Answer Marcio. is this in obj C? I'm using swift

Comment: yes it is.. translation should not be a problem as methods should have the same names

Comment: Cheers Marcio for your answer this helped me a lot in getting where i needed to go.